# Does Direct3D Mobile have a limit on the number of Draw*Primitive calls that can be made each frame?

Tags: windows-ce

I have Windows CE 6 running an Atom N270 with an Intel 945GSE chipset. I wrote a small test application for Direct3D Mobile and have been experiencing some strange behaviour. I can only call Draw*Primitive once per frame. Calling multiple times either results in a white screen as though Present failed (even though no error is given) or only the first call seems to be processed.

With the message handling omitted the body of the render loop is as follows:

```
HandleD3DMError(pD3DMobileDevice->Clear(0,0,D3DMCLEAR_TARGET | D3DMCLEAR_ZBUFFER ,0xA50AB0F,1.0f,0),_T("Clear"));
if(HandleD3DMError(pD3DMobileDevice->BeginScene(),_T("BeginScene")))
{
    HandleD3DMError(pD3DMobileDevice->SetTexture(0,pTexture), _T("SetTexture"));
    HandleD3DMError(pD3DMobileDevice->SetStreamSource(0,m_pPPVVB[0],sizeof(PrimitiveVertex)),_T("SetStreamSource Failed"));
    HandleD3DMError(pD3DMobileDevice->SetIndices(pIndexBuffer),_T("SetIndices failed"));
    HandleD3DMError(pD3DMobileDevice->DrawIndexedPrimitive(D3DMPT_TRIANGLELIST,0,0,NUM_TRIS*3,0,NUM_TRIS/2),_T("Draw Primitive 1"));
    //HandleD3DMError(pD3DMobileDevice->DrawIndexedPrimitive(D3DMPT_TRIANGLELIST,0,0,NUM_TRIS*3,NUM_TRIS/2 * 3,NUM_TRIS/2),_T("Draw Primitive 2"));

    HandleD3DMError(pD3DMobileDevice->SetStreamSource(0,0,0),_T("SetStreamSource Null Failed"));
    HandleD3DMError(pD3DMobileDevice->SetIndices(0),_T("SetIndices Null failed"));

    HandleD3DMError(pD3DMobileDevice->EndScene(),_T("EndScene"));
}
HandleD3DMError(pD3DMobileDevice->Present(0,0,0,0),_T("Present Failed"));
```

You can switch the two `DrawIndexedPrimitive()` lines and both render four triangles each, which is correct. However when they are both present nothing is rendered. The `HandleD3DMError()` function displays a message box when an error occurs. This is done all through initialisation too. No errors are displayed at any time.

I have tried drawing different primitive types and drawing non-indexed vertex buffers with no success. I am able to draw 10,000 triangles using a single buffer but trying to use multiple buffers fails (I assume it is related to the multiple Draw calls issue).

The documentation on MSDN does not mention any limitation on Draw calls. They even mention cases where you would need to make multiple Draw calls. The official samples I've looked at 
only ever call Draw*() once per frame too.

If I try and `BeginScene()` and `EndScene()` multiple times in the one frame nothing is rendered, not even the cleared colour.

I can provide all of the source if needed.

I appreciate any help anyone can give me.

Cheers

Comment: Further investigation indicates that the problem may be in the driver. The reference renderer works more as expected.